# MPMoviePlayerController stops and continues playing on 3G network

Tags: ios, url, stream, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm building an iPhone app for a local radio station. They have an URL where there's an MP3 available for live streaming. I set up MPMoviePlayerController to stream it, but every 10 seconds or so stops for around 4 seconds and continues playing.

I think this might be due to buffering. I'm wondering if there's any way to improve this and make it don't stop. On WiFi it works right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the mp3 is large then it will buffer thats the normal behavior, since it works fine on wifi then you most likely dont have any issue